# Indirect reference in Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

Using [freemarker](http://freemarker.org/), is there any way to reference a value indirectly along the lines of...

```
<#assign apple=fruit>
<#assign item=apple>
${${item}}
```

to produce the output 'fruit' without prior knowledge of what value item might contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [eval built-in](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_eval):

```
${item?eval}
```

That would only work if `item` contains a valid expression, though. There's also an `interpret` built-in which treats your string as a full template, I haven't used it myself.